# Dynamically cutting a div with Java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to be able to cut a div  without forcing it's content to resize . (basically having all content below a certain point to not display, or cutting off part of the div)

Sadly resizing the div will still alow images and some text to overflow

Is there any function to do this with Javascript or Jquery

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Just resizing the div, I'm asking if there is a cut function out there

Comment: Give That element overflow:hidden; to stop overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a max-height and hide the overflow. For example:

```
.cutDiv {
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```